# How to Select date from calendar using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, date, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraper using Selenium Python and stuck with this problem for long. I'm trying to select a custom date in the calendar but my code isn't working. Here is my code :

```py
report_date = "01-06-2020"    
dt = '{dt:%A}, {dt:%b} {dt.day}, {dt.year}'.format(dt=datetime.strptime(report_date,"%m-%d-%Y"))
dt1 = "'Select " + dt + "'"
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("[title='Select " + dt +"']").click()
```

This is throwing NoSuchElementException:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[title='Monday, Jan 6, 2020']"}
```

Here's what I see when I do Inspect from browser :

```html
<table><thead><tr><th class="datepick-week"><span title="Week of the year">Wk</span></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-0" title="Sunday">Su</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-1" title="Monday">Mo</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-2" title="Tuesday">Tu</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-3" title="Wednesday">We</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-4" title="Thursday">Th</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-5" title="Friday">Fr</a></th><th><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="datepick-dow-6" title="Saturday">Sa</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1577557800000" title="Select the entire week">52</a></td><td><span class="dp1577557800000  datepick-weekend datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1577644200000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1577730600000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1577817000000" class="dp1577817000000" title="Select Wednesday, Jan 1, 2020">1</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1577903400000" class="dp1577903400000" title="Select Thursday, Jan 2, 2020">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1577989800000" class="dp1577989800000" title="Select Friday, Jan 3, 2020">3</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578076200000" class="dp1578076200000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Saturday, Jan 4, 2020">4</a></td></tr><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1578162600000" title="Select the entire week">1</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578162600000" class="dp1578162600000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Sunday, Jan 5, 2020">5</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578249000000" class="dp1578249000000" title="Select Monday, Jan 6, 2020">6</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578335400000" class="dp1578335400000" title="Select Tuesday, Jan 7, 2020">7</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578421800000" class="dp1578421800000" title="Select Wednesday, Jan 8, 2020">8</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578508200000" class="dp1578508200000 datepick-selected" title="Select Thursday, Jan 9, 2020">9</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578594600000" class="dp1578594600000 datepick-today" title="Select Friday, Jan 10, 2020">10</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578681000000" class="dp1578681000000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Saturday, Jan 11, 2020">11</a></td></tr><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1578767400000" title="Select the entire week">2</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578767400000" class="dp1578767400000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Sunday, Jan 12, 2020">12</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578853800000" class="dp1578853800000" title="Select Monday, Jan 13, 2020">13</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1578940200000" class="dp1578940200000" title="Select Tuesday, Jan 14, 2020">14</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579026600000" class="dp1579026600000" title="Select Wednesday, Jan 15, 2020">15</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579113000000" class="dp1579113000000" title="Select Thursday, Jan 16, 2020">16</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579199400000" class="dp1579199400000" title="Select Friday, Jan 17, 2020">17</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579285800000" class="dp1579285800000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Saturday, Jan 18, 2020">18</a></td></tr><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1579372200000" title="Select the entire week">3</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579372200000" class="dp1579372200000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Sunday, Jan 19, 2020">19</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579458600000" class="dp1579458600000" title="Select Monday, Jan 20, 2020">20</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579545000000" class="dp1579545000000" title="Select Tuesday, Jan 21, 2020">21</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579631400000" class="dp1579631400000" title="Select Wednesday, Jan 22, 2020">22</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579717800000" class="dp1579717800000" title="Select Thursday, Jan 23, 2020">23</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579804200000" class="dp1579804200000" title="Select Friday, Jan 24, 2020">24</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579890600000" class="dp1579890600000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Saturday, Jan 25, 2020">25</a></td></tr><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1579977000000" title="Select the entire week">4</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1579977000000" class="dp1579977000000 datepick-weekend" title="Select Sunday, Jan 26, 2020">26</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1580063400000" class="dp1580063400000" title="Select Monday, Jan 27, 2020">27</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1580149800000" class="dp1580149800000" title="Select Tuesday, Jan 28, 2020">28</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1580236200000" class="dp1580236200000" title="Select Wednesday, Jan 29, 2020">29</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1580322600000" class="dp1580322600000" title="Select Thursday, Jan 30, 2020">30</a></td><td><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="dp1580409000000" class="dp1580409000000" title="Select Friday, Jan 31, 2020">31</a></td><td><span class="dp1580495400000  datepick-weekend datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td></tr><tr><td class="datepick-week"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dp1580581800000" title="Select the entire week">5</a></td><td><span class="dp1580581800000  datepick-weekend datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1580668200000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1580754600000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1580841000000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1580927400000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1581013800000  datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td><td><span class="dp1581100200000  datepick-weekend datepick-other-month">&nbsp;</span></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Hi, could you include the web you are trying to get

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @PriyankaJ Could you provide the webpage link of this? The inspect element content which you have provided doesn't have enough info for understanding.

Comment: @GaganTK , here is the link but I'm not sure if its helpful as it needs account login https://www6.mymicros.net/mainPortal.jsp

Comment: @PriyankaJ Yes, it needs login. Alternatively, if you could provide more source code of this webpage. You have provided `<td>` cell code in the question, please add the whole `<table>` HTML code in the question, it may give enough info.

Comment: let me try adding more html code.Thanks! View page source doesn't provide much useful information, just a bunch of java codes

Comment: @PriyankaJ Can you check if this works? `browser.find_element_by_id("dp1578249000000").click()`

Comment: @GaganTK, thanks for the response. I need to change the date dynamically, so  can't use dp1578249000000.

Comment: @PriyankaJ Yeah I know, it's dynamic and it's easy to change it through code. Can you just confirm if this 'click' works by using `browser.find_element_by_id("dp1578249000000").click()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205795/discussion-between-gagan-t-k-and-priyankaj).